# Matlab 3d plot/mesh for three column matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, plot, mesh

I have a three column matrix [year, month, data] and I'm trying to make a plot that compares monthly trends in the data across years. I've tried to do this using plot3, mesh, and ribbon.

Plot3(year, month, data) gets me pretty close to what I need, but the data is all connected even when it jumps from one year to the next, so what I get looks a lot like scribbling instead of one nice line for each year.

I thought using mesh or ribbon might fix this, but I'm stuck because the format for mesh is (X,Y,Z) where Z is a matrix, and if I treat my three columns separately, I'm left with only a vector for Z.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat your matrix [year month data] to use mesh or ribbon. For example, if your original matrix is like this:

```
[year month data]
 2001  1   100
 2001  2   101
 2001  3   102
 2002  1   104
 2002  2   105
 2002  3   106
```

Then you plot like this:

```
year=[2001,2002];
month=[1,2,3];
data=[100,104;101,105;102,106];
mesh(year,month,data);
% if it doesn't work, replace the last line with follow
% mesh(year,month,data');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So should the year and month be horizontal vectors of unique data points? When I reformat the data, should it be into a 2 column matrix like you showed, or does it matter? One of the problems I am running into is that my data is irregular - some months have multiple data points, and others have none, so I haven't been able to figure out how to reformat it neatly.

Comment: Yes, there should be only one value for a specific month in a year. Multiple values may be averaged. The "data" should be 2-dimensional matrix, whose size should equal to the length of month and year, as shown in the example.